# How to Make a Private Submit Button using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, submit

When a User clicks:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "2")  do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
<% end %>
```

how can we make the submitted information private? This is a **social media** web app so I'd like the User to have the ability to submit stuff without it being published to the feed or public profile for all the world to see.

For each of the _form's the User has the ability to click `<%= f.check_box :private_submit %>`. How can we integrate this function into the actual submit button so it's one less click for the User?

Thanks!

Comment: Use JQuery code.. very easy,

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand, what you actually want.

If the user should check the :private_submit and then click the submit button, you can put a condition in your controller depending on the value of params[:private_submit].

If you want to do this without the checkbox, you can place a second submit button into the form and then name both buttons:

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "2", name: 'public')  do %>
  ...
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "2", name: 'private')  do %>
  ...
```

and then evaluate the name of the button in your controller:

```
if params[:public]
  # the public action
elsif params[:private]
  # the private action
```